# Where can I view the logger.info used in a Python script?

Tags: python

This library has a lot of `logger.info` used in its code
https://github.com/Diaoul/subliminal/blob/a4113adb745dc5cd2da7254ee14802077237bb15/subliminal/core.py

Where do the logs go? How can I view them for debugging purposes?

Comment: That's going to depend on how exactly the code is used, what handlers are configured. It looks like there's a [`--debug` flag](https://github.com/Diaoul/subliminal/blob/master/subliminal/cli.py#L247) on the CLI that sets [logging to stdout](https://github.com/Diaoul/subliminal/blob/a4113adb745dc5cd2da7254ee14802077237bb15/subliminal/cli.py#L263-L268), for example.

Comment: You can't https://github.com/Diaoul/subliminal/blob/a4113adb745dc5cd2da7254ee14802077237bb15/subliminal/__init__.py  has a Nulhandler, so logs are never emit to somewhere

Comment: Hum, try `logging.getLogger("subliminal").addHandler(logging.StreamHandler())` before any code got executed

Comment: @azro a `NullHandler` like that just prevents warning and error logs going to stderr by default (see e.g. https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#configuring-logging-for-a-library); you can add other handlers, and the CLI entry point does.

Comment: You can also see that flag listed in the CLI help (`subliminal --help`) or [docs](https://subliminal.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/cli.html).

Comment: ```logging.getLogger("subliminal").addHandler(logging.StreamHandler())``` seems to be working. thx @azro

Comment: side question: since I am new to python... I don't understand how to define the opensubtitles username and password :(